# How can I selecting multiple columns, only one of which is distinct? (ORACLE SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to be able to do this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1(<LIST OF COLUMNS>)
SELECT <LIST OF ROWS> FROM (SELECT DISTINCT <OTHER COLUMNS> FROM TABLE_2);
```

How can I do this? I receive an error when I try to do it now.

Note that `<LIST OF COLUMNS>` is the same in both cases I use it, and also not that the fields in `<OTHER ROWS>` could, but do not necessarily exist in `<LIST_OF COLUMNS>`.

Comment: What? The question is very poorly worded. Can you clean it up a bit please?

Comment: Haha sorry about that, when it wasn't between code tags, anything enclosed in brackets was being hidden. Fixed.

Comment: @segfault You mean `<LIST OF COLUMNS>`, not `<LIST OF ROWS>`, right?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic yeah. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, a little philosophical treatise here...

"Distinct" means "reject duplicates". And to detect duplicated rows you have compare them for equality first.

If you just compare rows on **all columns**, everything is fine: two rows are either equal or they are not, there is no third possibility. So you always know whether a row should be rejected as a duplicate or not.

However, if you try to compare rows by comparing a **subset of their columns**, you run into trouble: rows that are equal when compared on the subset of their columns may not be equal when compared on all columns. So are they duplicates or not?

- If you consider them duplicates and reject one of the rows, you'll also be rejecting values that may not exist in the other row. You are effectively losing data (not to mention that *which* data you loose is random, so even the data you keep is essentially useless).
- If you don't consider them duplicates, then you are not really making them distinct on the column subset, contradicting what you were trying to do in the first place.

So making rows distinct on the subset of columns can only be done:

- if you don't keep the the other columns,
- or by "merging" values in other columns by subjecting them to aggregate functions such as `MAX`, `COUNT`, `SUM` etc..

This is the reason why `GROUP BY` must cover **all** non-aggregated columns. A `DISTINCT` is really just a `GROUP BY` on all columns.

Comment: Wow. Great point. So, really, there is no reason to not include all of the columns I am including in the new table.

Comment: I think the next question would be is there a way to select distinct on all of the columns being selected without needing to type all of their names again?

Comment: This is what `DISTINCT` does. As I said: "a DISTINCT is really just a GROUP BY on all columns". I could have added "all columns **selected**". OTOH, you should even be able to: `SELECT DISTINCT * ...` **if** you need all the column in the table.

Comment: It is not on all columns. Some are being left behind in this particular case. But I now understand what you were saying, and was not thinking about it wrong. I was redundantly SELECT ing columns then (SELECT DISTINCT 'same columns' FROM TABLE) when I could have done SELECT DISTINCT columns FROM TABLE. d'oh. Thanks again for the help.